# Landau-Lifschitz pseudotensor from Einstein equations (part I)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, curvature

In Landau-Lifschitz (Volume II):

Actually, it is not difficult to bring $T^{ik}$ to this form. To do this we start from the field equation

$$T^{ik}=\frac{1}{8\pi\kappa}\left(R^{ik}-\frac{1}{2}g^{ik}R\right)$$

and for $R^{ik}$ we have
$$R^{ik}=\frac{1}{2}g^{im}g^{kp}g^{ln}\Big\{\frac{\partial^2g_{lp} }{\partial x^m\partial x^n}+\frac{\partial^2g_{mn} }{\partial x^l\partial x^p}-\frac{\partial^2g_{ln} }{\partial x^m\partial x^p}-\frac{\partial^2g_{mp} }{\partial x^l\partial x^n}\Big\}$$

(we recall that at the point under consideration, all the $\Gamma^i_{kl}=0$). After simple transformations, the tensor $T^{ik}$ can be put in the form

$$T^{ik}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^l}\Big\{\frac{1}{16\pi\kappa}\frac{1}{-g}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^m}[(-g)(g^{ik}g^{lm}-g^{il}g^{km})]\Big\}$$

My question is: what is the hint to obtain the expression for $T^{ik}$? After a straightforward calculation, I have a long-expression different from this one.

$$R^{ik}-\frac{1}{2}g^{ik}R=\frac{1}{2}g^{im}g^{kp}g^{nl}\left(g_{lp},_{mn}+g_{mn},_{lp}-g_{mp},_{ln}-g_{ln},_{mp}\right)-$$

$$
-\frac{1}{2}g^{ik}g^{np}g^{ml}\left(g_{lp},_{mn}+g_{mn},_{lp}-g_{np},_{lm}-g_{lm},_{np}\right)
$$

Using the identities in the comments obtained this:
Using the identities I have this $$\frac{1}{2}\left((g^{ik}g^{mn}-g^{im}g^{nk})_{,mn}+g^{nl}g^{ik}_{,nl}+g^{im}g^{kp}g_{ln}g^{ln}_{,mp}-g^{ik}g^{ml}g_{np}g^{np}_{,lm}-g^{ik}g^{np}g_{lm}g^{lm}_{,np}\right)$$

How to proceed then?

Comment: Suggestion: Replace _stress-energy tensor_ with _Einstein tensor_ since this seems purely about calculating curvature.

Comment: Following landau Lifschitz trying to obtain stress-energy pseudo tensor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The derivation you refer to is done locally in a set of coordinates in which $g_{ik,l} = 0$, which can be also characterized as related to a set of [Riemann normal coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_coordinates) by a constant linear transform. This means, that you can make operations such as this one
$$g^{ij} (g_{kl,mn}) = (g^{ij}g_{kl,m})_{,n}$$
Another useful identity is $g^{ij}g_{jk,l} = -g^{ij}_{\;\,,l}g_{jk}$ since $g^{ij}g_{jk} = \delta^i_k\,,\; (\delta^i_k)_{,l} = 0$. One last formulas that you need is $g^{ij}g_{ij,k} = - g^{ij}_{\;\,,k}g_{ij} = g_{,k}/g$, where $g$ is the metric determinant (deriving this formula is a nice little exercise on its own).

It is a little bit laborous to get to the Landau-Lifschitz pseudotensor from the bottom up, but with the formulas above it is really just regrouping the terms in the right way. Start with regrouping the Einstein tensor as a divergence of a 3-index tensor using the first set of identities. Then identify terms that can be written as a $1/g \partial_m$ divergence within this tensor using the $g_{,k}/g$ identity and that should do the trick.

Comment: How to simplify this? $$g^{nl}g_{nl,mp}$$

Comment: You have to simplify the entire term: $g^{im}g^{kp}g^{nl}g_{nl,mp} = (g^{im}g^{kp}g^{nl} g_{nl,m})_{,p} = (g^{im}g^{kp}g^{nl} g_{nl,p})_{,m}$

Comment: Using the identities I have this $$\frac{1}{2}\left((g^{ik}g^{mn}-g^{im}g^{nk})_{,mn}+g^{nl}g^{ik}_{,nl}+g^{im}g^{kp}g_{ln}g^{ln}_{,mp}-g^{ik}g^{ml}g_{np}g^{np}_{,lm}-g^{ik}g^{np}g_{lm}g^{lm}_{,np}\right)$$

Comment: How to proceed then?

Comment: As said in the post, in the first step you want to make the Einstein tensor look like a coordinate divergence of a three-index (pseudo)tensor. Then you have to use the identities involving the metric determinant.

Comment: Thank you! It is derived.

Comment: Hello, Vojtech. The full expression for  Landau-Lifschitz pseudotensor is a long-expression. What is the hint to obtain the expression?

Answer (score 1):

You have to rearrange and factor terms in a particular way and then use properties of derivatives. For full derivation with explanations on each step, see [the blog](https://lantonov.blogspot.com/2012/02/landau-lifshitz-pseudotensor.html)